# Radiation Reaction and Acausal Acceleration

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

The Abraham -Lorentz formula for the radiation reaction force is $${\bf F}_{rad} {= \frac{\mu_0 q^2}{6 \pi c} {\bf \dot a}}$$ and when electric charges are moving Newtons Law for an applied force ${\bf F}$ changes from $m {\bf a} = {\bf F}$ to $${\bf F} = m {\bf a} - \frac{\mu_0 q^2}{6 \pi c} {\bf \dot a}.$$ Setting the external force ${\bf F} \equiv 0$ then gives the apparently bizarre result that an electric charge will spontaneously accelerate.

But, is this a correct interpretation? After all, consider a particle of mass $m$ being acted upon by some applied force $F$ on a flat surface. If friction is present, the frictional force is often put in the form $F_{friction} = \mu N$ where $N = mg$ is the normal reaction and Newton's Law becomes $$m a = F - \mu N,$$ with the understanding that the frictional force is only taken to be non-zero when the applied force is larger than the frictional force, that is you can't put the applied force to zero and argue this leaves the force $\mu N$ which accelerates the mass.

Why not the same for the radiation reaction force? That is, the radiative reaction force is only incorporated when it is smaller than the applied force?

Comment: Griffiths briefly discusses this issue in *Introduction to Electrodynamics, 3rd Ed., pp. 489-490*. He writes that this is still an open issue in classical electrodynamics and perhaps suggests that there is something deeply wrong with the idea of a point charge. He doesn't explicitly comment on (and nor am I aware of) the quantum mechanical counterpart of the problem/solution. Thanks for reminding me of this issue! :)